# How to write autocomplete with api in angular with material

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

I try to write with angular material . it doesn't work,
I get all the companies, but the autocomplete is not working at all.
I also wrote async pipe but I get all the time

> InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-title>find company</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-content>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input type="text" matInput aria-label="company" [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" />
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let company of companies | async" [value]="company.name"> {{ company.name }} </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

my component.ts:

```
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { startWith, map } from 'rxjs/operators';


export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  companies;
  filterOption: Observable<any[]>;

  observable: Observable<string>;
  myControl = new FormControl();

  constructor(private service: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCompanies();
  }

  // private filter(value: string): string[] {
  //   const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

  //   return this.companies.filter(companies => companies.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  // }

  getCompanies() {
    this.service.getCompanyFromApi().subscribe(companies => {
      this.companies = companies;
      this.filterOption = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(companies => {
          return this.filter(companies);
        })
      );

      console.log('before component ' + JSON.stringify(companies));
    });
  }
  private filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.companies.filter(company => company.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
}
```

Comment: You are subscribing to your API and assigning the response to `this.companies`, so you don't need to use the `AsyncPipe`. `AsyncPipe` is only required if `companies` is an Observable.

Comment: take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47673202/6294072

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  private filter(value: string): string[] {
        const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();        
        return this.companies.filter(company => company.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `filterOption` to the `ngOnInit` and in your HTML you need to loop over `filterOption` rather than `companies` so that only the filtered values will appear in the dropdown. The way you have currently set up the UI, you are looping over `companies` rather than the `filterOption`, so it is expected that all the `companies` will show.

```js
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
    companies: any[];
    filterOption: Observable<any[]>;
    myControl = new FormControl();

    constructor(private service: AuthService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getCompanies();
        this.filterOption = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
            startWith(''),
            map(companies => {
                return this.filter(companies);
            })
        );
    }

    getCompanies() {
        this.service.getCompanyFromApi().subscribe(companies => {
            this.companies = companies;
        });
    }
    private filter(value: string): string[] {
        const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

        return this.companies.filter(company => company.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
    }
}
```

Then in your HTML

```html
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let company of filterOption | async" [value]="company.name"> {{ company.name }} </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```